# Capture audio and video using Tabcapture API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrtc

I am building a chrome extension that can record session of a particular tab (session include both audio and video), for this i am using **tabcapture api** to get a stream of a tab session, this stream is then recorded using MRecordRTC
,I than save that recording(both audio and video as a seperate file) on a local machine the video file is **OK** but the audio file is very much distorted and sound like a bubbly voice. Below is the manifest.json and part of background.js file which i am using to record the session

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,  

  "name": "tabcap",
  "description": "This extension captures the session of selected tab.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "tabCapture",
    "activeTab",
    "http://localhost:1615/*"
  ],  

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon42.png",
    "default_icon": "icon64.png"
    },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://localhost:1615/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.6.1.min.js","myscript.js",]
    }
  ],

  "background":{
  "scripts": ["jquery-1.6.1.min.js","recordrtc.js","background.js"]
 }

}
```

**background.js**

```
var recorder = new MRecordRTC();
function handleCapture(stream) {
recorder.addStream(stream);
recorder.mediaType = { video: true, audio: true };
recorder.startRecording();
}

var MediaStreamConstraint = {
audio: true,
video: true,
videoConstraints: {
    mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
        minWidth: 1920,
        maxWidth: 1920,
        minHeight: 1080,
        maxHeight: 1080
    }
}
};

function captureCurrentTab() {
chrome.tabCapture.capture(MediaStreamConstraint, handleCapture);
}

function stopCapturing() {
// stops the recording and save audio and video     
}
```

some other finding while testing the **tabcapture api**

- the embedded audio is not audible while capturing the tab.
- if just the audio is recorded using tabcapture api then the saved file is not distorted and sounds Ok

  is there something missing in my manifest.jon file or i am not following the correct sequence of **tabcapture api**

Comment: The manifest file seems fine, have you check on this project for guidance? https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/Chrome-Extensions/tabCapture

Comment: Yes i have seen the project, but it is not dealing with audio capturing

Comment: As a test, try recording at a resolution less than HD (say 640x480).  It may be a load issue

Comment: @jesup your test works but the video quality becomes so bad, is there a solution for getting both audio and video in good quality?

Comment: That implies I'm right - it's a load issue.  Realtime full-HD encoding at a high framerate is Not Easy.  Try reducing the framerate instead.

Comment: Did you find the solution for capturing audio?